# Why does my app gives out of bound memory exception in android devices API:25 or lower but works fine with the same devices with an higher API?

Tags: android, image, kotlin

The problem is because I am using very large images on small or medium devices... By the way what is the best solution to display those big images without slowing down the app too much? I would prefer not having to resize all images manually to adapt to different device sizes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those images delived with your app (in your project/APK file/AAB file)? If this is the case, AndroidStudio can help you with resizing.

Comment: That seems nice for my case, could you tell how to access this feature?

Comment: right click on the `res` folder in AndroidStudio and select `New`>`Image Asset`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with recommended libraries like Picasso & Glide.
Both are handy and super easy to use.
These will handle your image processing portion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).